# sqlite3 exception database is locked

Tags: iphone, sqlite

If I open database in one function and close in the same function, then again open it with same database object but in another function (of same class) - will that cause a 'database is locked' exception?

I should mention that I'm dealing with two different tables of the database. I get the error when I try to `UPDATE` or `INSERT` in the table, and never for `SELECT` queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution. I wasn't finalizing the `sqlite3_stmt`, that's why this was happening. So, whenver you use any `'sqlite3_stmt *statement;'`, make sure you properly finalize it by calling `'sqlite3_finalize(statement)';`

Check out [this link](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=DatabaseIsLocked) a better description.